# An error occurred while preparing the query for linked server - SQL Server + Teradata

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, teradata

In SQL Server I have defined the following Job agent and the following step:

```
INSERT INTO dse.dwh_log
SELECT *
FROM
OPENQUERY(DWH_Production, 
'
select
    cast(cast(LogonDate as format ''yyyy-mm-dd'') as char(10)) || '' '' ||
    cast(cast(LogonTime as format ''99:99:99.999'') as char(12)) as LogonTime,
    UserName,
    substr(StatementText,1,8000) as RequestText
from
    p_sys_ms_logging.accesslog_hst
where      statementtype = ''select''
and databasename  in (''CDR'', ''cdr30_targetdb'')
and statementtext is not null
and logondate > current_date - 2')
```

The error message I am getting is:

> Executed as user: XYZ. An error occurred while preparing the query
>   select cast(cast(LogonDate as format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as char(10)) || ' ' || cast(cast(LogonTime as format '99:99:99.999') as char(12)) as LogonTime, UserName, substr(StatementText,1,8000) as RequestText from p_sys_ms_logging.accesslog_hst where statementtype = 'select' and databasename in ('CDR', 'cdr30_targetdb')  and statementtext is not null  and logondate > current_date - 2"
>
> for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DWH_Production".
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7321).
>   NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (2) without succeeding. The step failed.

The duration is about an hour, but the query should run in around 5 minutes.
I am retrieving the data from the Teradata database, and transferring them to SQL Server.

Does anyone know why am I getting this message (on Google I did not find anything that could help me), and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: The syntax of the resulting SELECT is correct. Does it work when you directly run it against Teradata?

Comment: it does - of course when I replace double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Actually when I take the query from the error message and run it without changing anything, I get a result set from the database. The query runs without error. That is why I decided to ask the help from Stackoverflow.

Comment: That's why I did, too (after changing the table name to `dbc.accesslog`). Sorry, I can't help you any further...

Comment: Can you verify that the query is actually getting to the destination server?  I'd check for errors in the teradata log tables.

Comment: I did check the teradata log tables, and did not find any record of accessing the teradata table. There must be some problem with SQL Server, but which...?